# Getting the last commit date of a specific remote branch in Git repo from local

Tags: github, git-branch, git-commit

How can we get the last commit date of a specific branch in remote Git - either through API or CLI?
For example: [image]

In the attached image, "generics" is the branch in the repo, and 5-March-2013 is the last commit date for that branch. I'm looking to get this "5-March-2013" info by specifying the branch name as "generics".

Comment: In the CLI (shell), there is no "remote Git": there's just the local repository. You have the whole thing, so you just look at the commits, which you already have. But if you don't want to clone the repository, then you must pick a hosting site and its API, because each hosting site has (usually minor) differences between how you will do this.

Comment: Hence, your question needs to be pinned down: do you want to use *Git*, or do you want to use some *web hosting API?* If the latter, which one?

Comment: Which part is giving you problems, finding the last commit or extracting the commit date from the metadata?

Comment: @torek Hi! I'm looking for GitHub. In the screenshot above (from GitHub), there is a data shown, I'm trying to extract this out. My use case is not about "development" rather "reporting". I'm trying to provide a reporting page where I can give details about the branch (provided as input) like last commit date, committed by etc (as output). If CLI/API from GitHub can provide this, I should be able to send the request.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Hi! Git/GitHub newbie here.. I would say both. Basically, I'm not able to figure out a means to extract the date info given a branch name in a repo. I had tried the git show -s format="%cd" <branchName> approach, but this doesnt work against a remote repo/branch it seems. Getting the "last" commit date is my intention, but just being able to list all commit dates (if that's easier) is okay for me to start with.. I was wondering if there's a way to query for this info against a branch name as input.

Comment: GitHub mainly provide a web interface and API, but they do have the `gh` CLI for some systems: see https://cli.github.com/ for instance.

Answer (score 0):

As a generic solution, you may do a fetch and then `git log` the remote tracking branch:

```
git fetch origin
git log origin/generics
```

Then just check the date of the commit on the top of the log.